# How to quote part of a subprocess.run list?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ssh, subprocess, rsync

I need to quote part of the rsync line that subprocess.run uses that contains the ssh parameters, unfortunately nothing I have tried has worked so far.

Can someone please advise me on the correct way to quote the ssh parameters, so that it will run under rsync.

At first I had a list of lists that got passed to subprocess.run, that fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tmp.py", line 20, in <module>
    process = subprocess.run(rsync_cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 423, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1295, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Flatten it to an ordinary list:

```
Unexpected remote arg: example.com:/var/log/maillog
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1361) [sender=3.1.2]
```

Which makes sense, as part of the command line for rsync needs to be quoted.

So I try to quote it:

```
rsync: Failed to exec /usr/bin/ssh -F /home/rspencer/.ssh/config -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=24 -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ControlMaster=autoask -o ControlPath=/run/user/1000/foo-ssh-master-%C -l root -p 234 -o Compression=yes: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85) [Receiver=3.1.2]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

Which is due, I expect, to it being a string instead of a list. Although I'm guessing and that does not make complete sense to me.

Summarized code of my last attempt:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess

ssh_args = [
    "-F",
    "/home/rspencer/.ssh/config",
    "-o",
    "PreferredAuthentications=publickey",
    "-o",
    "StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new",
    "-o",
    "TCPKeepAlive=yes",
    "-o",
    "ServerAliveInterval=5",
    "-o",
    "ServerAliveCountMax=24",
    "-o",
    "ConnectTimeout=30",
    "-o",
    "ExitOnForwardFailure=yes",
    "-o",
    "ControlMaster=autoask",
    "-o",
    "ControlPath=/run/user/1000/foo-ssh-master-%C",
    "-l",
    "root",
    "-p",
    "234",
]
rsync_params = []
src = "example.com:/var/log/maillog"
dest = "."

# Build SSH command
ssh_cmd = ["/usr/bin/ssh"] + ssh_args

# Use basic compression
ssh_cmd.extend(["-o", "Compression=yes"])

ssh_cmd = " ".join(ssh_cmd)
ssh_cmd = f'"{ssh_cmd}"'

# Build rsync command
rsync_cmd = ["/usr/bin/rsync", "-vP", "-e", ssh_cmd] + rsync_params + [src, dest]

# Run rsync
process = subprocess.run(rsync_cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

if process.returncode != 0:
    print(process.stderr.decode("UTF-8").strip())
```

What the correct command would look like on the command line:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -vP -e "/usr/bin/ssh -F /home/rspencer/.ssh/config -o \
PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new -o \
TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=24 -o \
ConnectTimeout=30 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ControlMaster=autoask \
-o ControlPath=/run/user/1000/foo-ssh-master-%C -l root -p 234 -o \
Compression=yes" example.com:/var/log/maillog .
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the trick is to not try to quote it.

I removed the following line and it worked without further modification:

```py
ssh_cmd = f'"{ssh_cmd}"'
```

I've read so much documentation and missed it until asking the question. Murphy.

Rereading the post "[How not to quote argument in subprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130538/how-not-to-quote-argument-in-subprocess#comment14587391_11130550)" and finally understanding what Greg Hewgill was saying helped me. I blame lack of sleep.

"If you use quotes on the shell command line, then put the whole contents in one element of `args` (without the quotes). ..." - Greg Hewgill